# phpMyAdmin MySQLi extension error

Tags: php, mysql

Oh, this way to make code on this site...

I followed tutorial on this site to install [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin):
http://www.raspipress.com/2012/09/tutorial-install-phpmyadmin-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Here it's what I have installed:
**pastebin.com/fSnGNrAS**

When I try to get into `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` I have a "mysqli extension is missing" error.

Uncommented in php.ini:

```
mysqli.allow_local_infile = on
```

added

```
extension=mysqli.so (but folder /etc/php5/apache2/extensions is empty)
```

And trying to figure out how to fix this error.

PS: I remember that before PHP 5 I have installed some MySQLi connector to Python, and I can't figure out about its connection to this error now. I think it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

First run this command (you may have already done this but lets be sure):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

then restart Apache (which I think is the actual cause of your problem), by doing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart.
```

Answer (score 0):

> phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your
>   PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

*If you are running php7.0*

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart.
```

Maybe, you will also need:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring 

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```